# Keep receiving NULL when reading from the arduino to the c++ program

Tags: c++, winapi, arduino

I use windows API to connect the arduino through serial connection in my c++ program.

The arduino will send a byte every second, and c++ program should read that byte and print on the screen.

This is my arduino code.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write('a');
  delay(1000);  
}
```

There are the members in the Serial class

```
    //Serial comm handler
    HANDLE hSerial;
    //Connection status
    bool connected;
    //Get various information about the connection
    COMSTAT status;
    //Keep track of last error
    DWORD errors;
    //transform error message to be stored in a string variable
```

This is my read function in my C++ program

```
int Serial::ReadData(char buffer)
{
    //Number of bytes we'll have read
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;

    //Use the ClearCommError function to get status info on the Serial port
    ClearCommError(this->hSerial, &this->errors, &this->status);

    cout << this->status.cbInQue << " Bytes in the queue have not been read" << endl;
    //Check if there is something to read
    if(this->status.cbInQue>0)
    {
        //Try to read the require number of chars, and return the number of read bytes on success
        if(ReadFile(this->hSerial, (void *)&buffer, 1, &bytesRead, NULL) )
        {
            return bytesRead;
        }

    }
    //If nothing has been read, or that an error was detected return 0
    return 0;
}
```

This is my Serial constructor, if needed

```
Serial::Serial(string portName, char use)
{
    //We're not yet connected
    this->connected = false;

    DWORD authority;
    if (use == 'w'){
        authority = GENERIC_WRITE;
    }
    else if (use == 'r'){
        cout << "read" << endl;
        authority = GENERIC_READ;
    }
    else if (use == 'b'){
        authority = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE; 
    }
    else{
        cout << "the second parameter of the initialization of the Serial object is wrong" << endl;
        cout << "It can only be w or r" << endl;
    }

    //Try to connect to the given port through CreateFile
    this->hSerial = CreateFile(portName.c_str(),
            authority,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);

    //Check if the connection was successful
    if(this->hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << GetLastErrorAsString() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //If connected we try to set the comm parameters
        DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};

        //Try to get the current
        if (!GetCommState(this->hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
        {
            //If impossible, show an error
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Define serial connection parameters for the arduino board
            dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
            dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
            dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
            //Setting the DTR to Control_Enable ensures that the Arduino is properly
            //reset upon establishing a connection
            dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

             //Set the parameters and check for their proper application
             if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
             {
                printf("ALERT: Could not set Serial Port parameters");
             }
             else
             {
                 //If everything went fine we're connected
                 this->connected = true;
                 //Flush any remaining characters in the buffers
                 PurgeComm(this->hSerial, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                 //We wait 2s as the arduino board will be reseting
                 Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main program

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{     
    char use = 'r'; //r for read, w for write, b for both
    Serial* SP = new Serial("COM4", use);    // adjust as needed

    char input;
    int num_bytes_read;
    while(SP->IsConnected())
    {
        cout << "connect successes!" << endl;
        num_bytes_read = SP->ReadData(input);
        cout << num_bytes_read << " " << (int) input << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When printing to the screen, I cast the char variable 'input' to int to check the ascii code of the value stored in the char variable.

Finally, it is the output of my c++ program

```
connect successes!
1 Bytes in the queue have not been read
1 0
```

It seems that it does receive the data, but why it prints NULL instead of 'a'?

I use Arduino/Genuino Uno (this is what I see when I check the "Tools" button in the Arduino IDE) and Windows 10

Thank you for considering my request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ arguments are passed by vaule... unless they are passed by reference. So change this line:

```
int Serial::ReadData(char buffer)
```

to:

```
int Serial::ReadData(char &buffer)
```

Or else, when you read into `buffer` you are actually reading into a variable local to `ReadData` and do not modify `input` from `main`.

Arguably, it would be better if you change it into something like:

```
int Serial::ReadData(char *buffer, int len)
```

And then, in `main` you call it writing:

```
num_bytes_read = SP->ReadData(&input, 1);
```

That way, in the future, when you want to read more data, you will be able to to it with just one call.

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally forget that!

I have used char* to complete this task.

Just for my curiosity, when I use string&, why does it print garbled?

The following is part of the garbled.


((((((((((((((((((((((  
                                                              abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz      VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0



Thank you very much!

Comment: I second the two-argument approach, but vote for `size_t len`.

Comment: @DavidChen: About the `string&` you should show how you use it, because if you are using `ReadFile(..., &string, ...)` that will not work because `string` is a complex class not a simple byte array.

Comment: @rodrigo I just use `string&` in the way you have mentioned. Now I know why it does not work because of your explanation, thanks a lot!